# Deleting a node from a Queue

Tags: c, queue

I had been working on making a Queue and trying to manage it. I needed a Queue to keep a record of active clients in my udp single server/multiple clients application (I am forced to use udp so please don't suggest shifting to tcp).

There is single Server and x number of clients. Whenever a client sends its first message, the ip number and port number of this client is push()ed into a Queue.

Then, after every 5 sec, server pop()s ip and port number out of the Queue and sends a message to client with this ip and port number. If client replies back within a specific time, it is considered "Active" but if no repy receieved from the client within a time out, the Client is considered dead and must be removed from the Queue.

Now the problem is that how to delete this node. One option is simply adding NULL in place of this node but I want to completely delete this node from the Queue.

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Below is my code:

```
struct node
{
    int rollno;
    struct node*n;
};

struct node* create()
{
    struct node*q;
    q=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    return q;
}
void push(struct node*cur)
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head = cur;
        tail = cur;
        start = cur; //keeps a track of first node
    }
    else
    {
        struct node*f;
        f=head;
        head->n = cur;
        head=head->n; //keep updating head
    }
}

struct node* pop()
{
    struct node*p;
    struct node*s = NULL;p = tail;

    if (p == head && tail != head) /*if at the end of list, display starting from first element as Queue is FIFO*/
    {
        p = start;
        tail=p->n;
        s = p;
        display(s);
        return s;
    }

    if(p == NULL)
    {
        if (start == NULL)  //if no emelemt yet in the Queue
           return NULL;
        else // if at the End of list, go back to start
           {
              p = start;
              tail=p->n;
              s = p;
           }
    }
    else 
    {
           tail=p->n; //keep updating tail
           s = p;
    }

    display(s);
    return s;
}

void main()
{
   while(1)
   {
        //if new client
    struct node*j;  
    j = create();
        // j= ip and port of client.
    j->n=NULL;
        push(j); 
        //after every 5 secs
        {
           pop();
           //if client fails to reply
           {
              delete node.
           }
        }
   }



}
```

Comment: Not related to your question though, have you went wrong with logic in `else` part of in function `push`??

Comment: @Ayesha what do you mean by "completely delete"?do you want to know about free function- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/

Comment: How do you create a new node anyway? Don't see any memory allocation for new objects, all you do is assign NULLs.

Also, push and pop look suspiciously a lot like something intended for a stack implementation, not a queue.

Comment: Thank you for your post. The code works fine for pushing and popping

Comment: Even if I use free(x), the node previous to x must update its next node from x to x->n. How will I do that?

Comment: Well, there was no `create` before your edit ;)

Comment: @rajraj you're confusing head for insertion at the beginning but it really is insertion at the end.

Comment: @mohit,Ayesha: Got it.:-)

Comment: This is really cnfusing for me too. I think I'll have to change the entire code and go for some other option

Comment: Can I use an array to store active clients. e.g if one client is Active, array[0] has its information, for nest client, array[1] created and so on... Now if array[3] is Inactive, is there a way I delete array[3] and now array[4] becomes array[3] and so on..

Comment: @rajraj: you added an answer a moment ago. That seemed to be a good solution then why did you delete it?

Comment: @AyeshaHassan: At first, I didn't check for start and head. Have modified the answer. See whether it will do something good for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DPG said, linked list is more suited here.

For now, do you need something like this?

```
void freenode(struct node* n)
{
    struct node* p = start;
    struct node* last = start;
    while (p != NULL) {
        if (p == n) {
            if (p == start) {
                if (p->n = NULL) {
                    head = NULL;
                    start = NULL;
                    tail = NULL;
            }
            else {
                if (tail == start)
                    tail = start->n;
                    start = start->n;
            }
            }
            else if (p == head) {
                head = last;
            head->n = NULL;
            }
            else {
                last->n = p->n;
            }
            free(p);
            break;
        }
        last = p;
        p = p->n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works great if node to be deleted is in the middle but doesnot work if node to be deleted is at the start or at the end of the Queue :(

Comment: Please have a look at it if you can help me with that :(

Comment: Sorry, i have little bit of confusion there, a push a made to the `head`, right? and shouldn't `start` be modified to `tail` after a pop?? Have modified code a little, for the `head` case, if it is what i have understood.

Comment: Yes you're right, push() is made to head. start always is the first node. and tail is which node is being currently pop()ed out.

Comment: In a queue, if one element is popped out, it is removed from the queue. You don't expect that?? You still want it to remain there?

Comment: No, the code is perfect now if the element to be deleted is in the mid of the queue or even if it is the head (i.e. last element of the queue), but the problem arrises when the element to be deleted is the first element of the queue.

Comment: I have made changes to code for deletion of node at head or at start. The code is perfect now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Since it's meant to be a queue, deletion would happen only at the front meaning you only need to get rid of the head element. Something like:

```
void delete()
{
    node* temp = head;  /* store the head the pointer so we can free it later */
    head = head->next;  /* make the node next to head be the head */
    free(temp);         /* free the original head pointer */
}
```

Taking into account your comment, if I've understood correctly you need to delete any node in the linked list.

This is a deletion function for a node in a linked list that takes care of three 3 separate cases - if the node to be deleted is a head, if it's a tail or if it is inbetween (note that you would need to provide your own functionality for identifying a dead node):

```
/* need id argument to know which node needs to be deleted
 * we need to already know which node is dead */
void delete_arbitrary(int id) 
{
    if (head->rollno == id) /* id matches that of head, let's delete it */
    {
        node* temp = head;  /* store the head pointer so we can free it later */
        head = head->next;  /* make the node next to head be the head */
        free(temp);         /* free the original head pointer */
    }
    else /* node somewhere down the line, let's find it */
    {
        node* curr = head->next /* start from the node after the head */
        node* prev; /* this is to keep track of the previous node */

        while(curr->rollno != id && curr != NULL)
        {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        if (curr == NULL) /* didn't find it so let's report it and quit */
        {
            printf("Node not found\n");
        }
        else if (curr->next == NULL) /* we're at the tail */
        {
            node* temp = tail; /* store it for later deletion */
            tail = prev; /* the previous node is now the tail */
            free(temp); /* free the old tail */
        }
        else /* it's somewhere in between */
        {
            prev->next = curr->next; /* the previous node now points to the one after the current */
            free(curr); /* get rid of the current pointer */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I think node should be deleted only if the corresponding client has died.

Comment: Well she can add the validation logic for that, but this is basically how a head is removed from a queue.

Comment: This doesn't looks like queue to me (except that she mentions this in her question). I think she wants to remove all nodes who are dead after 5 secs.

Comment: Yes, the node should be deleted only when the corresponding client has died.

Comment: Okay, I've put some code that deletes a node in a linked list based on the id of that node. I don't know how you identify which node is dead, but if you know then this function should help you delete it. Please let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: @Nobilis: Thanks a lot. I am going to try it :)

Comment: @Nobilis: Thanks a lot. I am going to try it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use **malloc** function to allocate memory for your nodes, you can release that memory using **free** function. Here you haven't allocate memory for j pointer and it is a bug.

In your application, you have to check whether each element is active in every 5 minutes and if any node is inactive at the moment, you have to delete it. So, I think you don't need a FIFO data structure. It's better to use linked list data structure.